# MS Word -- Convert a nested list to document headings

Tags: microsoft-word, documents

I have a tabbed list like this:

```
Big Idea
    Smaller idea
    Smaller idea 2
Big Idea
    Smaller idea 3
```

I can easily convert it to a nested list like this:

- Big idea

  - Smaller idea
  - Smaller idea 2
- Big idea 2

  - Smaller idea 3

It has hundreds of items.  How can I automatically convert it to a structure of nested Headings?

**Big Idea**

***Smaller Idea***

***Smaller Idea 2***

**Big Idea 2**

***Smaller Idea***

---

I'm using the latest version of MS Word.

Comment: How are you converting it in the first place?

Comment: @CoscoTech Just highlighting the whole thing and clicking the bulleted list icon.  Word knows that tabbed lists should become bulleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out-- it turns out to be pretty easy.

1. Highlight the list.
2. Click the arrow next to the "nested list" icon and select the nested list with "Heading 1" etc.

[image: MS Word Nested List Tool; Highlighting the multi-level headings list.]

That's it, you're done.  You can edit the style if you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully automatic but still simple
Select the entire bullet
Click down arrow beside bullet icon and select none
Click down arrow beside the word paragraph and set left indent to 0. 
All the bullets will be now on start of line. 
You may apply any formatting 
If you want to do it ftequently you may record a macro to do it automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to get a bulleted list that starts at the beginning of the line.  I'm trying to get a list of nested headings.